# segmentation fault with numba and matplotlib in conda python

Tags: python, conda

I created a conda environment with

```
conda create --name py27 python=2.7 numba numpy matplotlib
pip install ipdb
```

Then running a simple main.py as (after `source activate py27`)

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get

> [1]    32352 segmentation fault (core dumped)  python main.py

commenting on pyplot line then it runs smoothly. This happens for more complicated tests as well.

Anything I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, this question makes no sense since i realized the problem is only with matplotlib. Numba has nothing to do

Comment: I opened a flag because I would like to delete the question. If anybody has other tip to proceed with this, please let me know

Comment: Try uninstalling matplotlib from `conda` and re-install it using `pip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after matplotlib import setting

```
mpl.use('TkAgg')  # or whatever other backend that you want
```

solves the problem. As @Nils Werner added, unisntalling from `conda` and using `pip` solved the issue